# How do　I apply the Squeeze Theorem on this example?

Tags: calculus

I am currently having trouble with the Squeeze Theorem and how it applys for this question. I know that the theorem states that if I for example f(x) and g(x) and if h(x) is in between the two, then if f(x) = g(x) then h(x) should equal those two as well. Of course that's the easy part, the hard part for me is applying that knowledge. The question is:

Q:

Suppose $$x^4 < f(x) < x^2$$
if |x| < 1

and

$$x^2 < f(x) < x^4$$

if |x| > 1

If there limits exist find:

1. lim x-->-1 f(x)
2. lim x--> 0 f(x)

Can someone guide me with the steps as to how to solve for this? How does the absolute value affect the question?

My Guess:
I was thinking it was infinity for first one, but I am obviously wrong here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain the second part.

Since we're looking around $0$, we only need to consider how $f$ behaves when $\lvert x \rvert < 1$. So, we know that $x^4 < f(x) < x^2$. We also note that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^4 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^2 = 0.$$
Hence, by the squeeze theorem, $f(x)$ must tend to the same limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, i.e.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow -1} f(x)$ can be obtained similarly as both $x^2$ and $x^4$ tend to the same limit as $x \rightarrow -1$.

Comment: Are we plugging in 0 as we usually do when finding the limit?

Comment: @user3718584 Yes, since we're finding the limits of $x^2$ and $x^4$, we can just plug in $0$ to get the limit.

Comment: Doesn't the absolute value affect the answer? Does it change if the question didn't use absolute value x, but just plain x instead?

Comment: That's mainly my #1 concern right now, as the absolute value is worrying me.

Comment: @user3718584 So basically you're concerned with how $f(x)$ behaves near $-1$, right? Let's find $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+} f(x)$. Since we are approaching from the right side of $-1$, we have $\lvert x \rvert <1$, and so, $x^4 < f(x) < x^2$. Now, we know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+} x^2 = \lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+} x^4 = 1$, so the squeeze theorem tells us that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+} f(x) = 1$. You should be able to figure out what $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^-} f(x)$ is along similar line of reasoning.

Comment: but if we plug in negative into absolute, doens't it just turn positive? wouldn't it be not smaller than 1 ?

Comment: No. For example, if you consider $x=-2$, since $\lvert -2 \rvert > 1$, you know that $(-2)^2 = 4 < f(-2) < 16 = (-2)^4$. The absolute value does not affect the function itself at all.

Comment: One last question, if we are approaching -1 from right side, are we also including positive numbers. Wouldn't we have |x| > 1 instead?

Comment: Actually wouldn't |x| < 1 regardless of which side we approach -1 from?

Comment: Nope, if $x \rightarrow -1^-$, then $x < -1$, which would imply $\lvert x \rvert > 1$.

Comment: So if we coem from left side we try stuff like -1.1 and |-1.1| = 1.1 > 1. Then if we apporach from right we try like -0.99 which is |-0.99| = 0.99 < 1

Comment: Exactly. That's why when we were doing $\lim_{x \rightarrow -1^+} f(x)$, we said that $x^4 < f(x) < x^2$ and used the squeeze theorem there.

Comment: OKay, I just gave you a check mark! I had to go do something for a while.